Chrome content security policy blocks use of inline scripts and stylesheets
I am trying to test in whatsapp web a well known tool called zapixweb which allows for exporting chat data from within whatsapp web in the browser. Once copying the javascript code into the browser console and upon running the script I am always met with an error for security content policies.  I will be the first to admit that I am not the most knowledgeable when it comes to such issues so If anyone has any advice to point me in the right direction or has come across this issue before and resolved all help would be appreciated. Thanks
